# R dygraph prediction plotted along with original values

Tags: r, time-series, dygraphs

I need to plot a time series in Dygraphs, where multiple time series are plotted together.

As data we can use

```
df <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
```

as is done on dygraphs website: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

However I would like to make the prediction of both time series continue in the same image as the original data. I have made a crude drawing of what I want to achieve

[image]

One way is naturally to make the predictions with i.e auto.arima separately and then combine the data once again. I am wondering if there is a functionality, that can do it all in one shot?

Comment: In your case I would synchronize the charts [like so](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html) :
Zooming and panning on any of the charts will zoom and pan all the others. Selecting points on one will select points on the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is answered in "Upper/Lower Bars" section at the same website: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-upper-lower-bars.html.
You need to make your prediction model, for example:

```
hw <- HoltWinters(mdeaths)
p <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 36, prediction.interval = TRUE)
all <- cbind(ldeaths, p)
```

and plot de graph:

```
dygraph(all, "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dySeries("mdeaths", label = "Actual") %>%
  dySeries(c("p.lwr", "p.fit", "p.upr"), label = "Predicted")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is:

```
hw <- HoltWinters(mdeaths)
predictedMen <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 12 ,prediction.interval = TRUE)
hw <- HoltWinters(fdeaths)
predictedWomen <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 12 ,prediction.interval = TRUE)
predictedMen %>%  class
AuxF <- function(x){
  x <- data.frame(date=  as.Date(x), Vuelos=as.matrix(x) )
  x <- read.zoo(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  return(x)
}
DF <- zoo( 
  cbind(
rbind( cbind( upr = AuxF(mdeaths), fit= AuxF(mdeaths) ,  lwr = AuxF(mdeaths)) 
   ,  cbind( upr = AuxF(predictedMen[ , 2]), fit= AuxF(predictedMen[ , 1]) ,  lwr = 
AuxF(predictedMen[ , 3])) )
, rbind( cbind( upr = AuxF(fdeaths), fit = AuxF(fdeaths) ,  lwr = AuxF(fdeaths)) 
     ,  cbind( upr = AuxF(predictedWomen[ , 2]), fit = AuxF(predictedWomen[ , 1]) ,  
wr = AuxF(predictedWomen[ , 3])) ) 
) )    
names(DF) <- c("predictedMen.upr", "predictedMen.fit", "predictedMen.lwr",
"predictedWomen.upr", "predictedWomen.fit", "predictedWomen.lwr")
dygraph(DF, main = "Predicted Lung Deaths (UK)") %>%
dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dySeries(c("predictedMen.upr", "predictedMen.fit", "predictedMen.lwr"), label = 
"Men")
%>%   dySeries(c("predictedWomen.upr", "predictedWomen.fit", "predictedWomen.lwr"),
label = "Women") %>% 
  dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set1"))  %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 200)
```